# Interactive flash console

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, console, flash-builder

I've recently started programming in Flash with Flash Builder. Coming from JavaScript I'm used to an "interactive" console (Chrome's default console) - by interactive I mean I can for example click an Object to show it's properties, and execute code at run-time. It also shows in which file and at what row the "trace()" statement came from.

Is this possible in flash?
I've tried "FlashFireBug" and "Vizzy" this far without luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, to an extent. Flash Builder is based on Eclipse, so it has an extensive debug framework installed by default. To do anything, you'll first need to insert a breakpoint (double click the gray bar on the left side of a line, or right click>Add Breakpoint). As with JS in a dev console, that will stop code execution at that precise line and allow you to step through, step over, etc. Additionally, it will give you access to the "Expressions" and "Variables" panes.

The "Variables" pane gives you access to all of the objects within the scope of the line at the breakpoint. With this, you can look at every single property for every single object. You can also change these properties to different values. This doesn't work as nicely as with a JS console, however, because of how strictly typed AS3 is. You are limited in what you can change, which is simply the primitive datatypes: Number, String, Array, Object. Anything more than that and I do not believe you can change values.

The "Expressions" pane gives you the ability to call a property or run an expression and get a full readout of the value (so you don't have to dig for an object, you can just call it). This is, again, limited. What you do in this pane will not actually change anything. You can run a function and it will return the value, but it won't modify anything in the program.

You can type in the console itself, but it doesn't do anything.

As far as I am aware, there is no way to get a trace location. I generally do any trace that will remain in place for an extended period of time like so:

```
trace( "[ClassName] trace output" );
```

This way I at least know what class it is coming from. You can also automate that bit if you create your own trace function (using a static method, most likely). Beyond that, I don't think you can do much more.

The main difference between JS and AS3 is that AS3 is a compiled language. A lot of the code is actually run and calculated at compile-time so that there is less to do at runtime. JS runs everything as it is called, which is why you can modify the code in the dev tools and call it and that change will execute. As far as I am aware, what you seek is simply not possible with AS3 due to this limitation, unfortunately.